# "forgetting base point"-map properties

Tags: general-topology

I need help with the following problem:

> Let $P:\pi_1(X,x_0)\to S(X)$ be the map from the set of homotopy classes of loops based at $x_0$ to the set of homotopy classes without restriction on the base point, induced by "forgetting" the base point. Show that $P$ is well-defined, it's surjective iff $X$ is path-connected and $P([f])=P([g])$ iff $f,g$ are conjugate.

*well-defined*: Let $v,w$ be two homotopic loops based at $x_0$, i.e. $[v]=[w]\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$ (via homotopy $H$ preserving the base point). We need to show that $P(v)=P(w)$. But $H$ also is a homotopy between $v,w$ if we disregard the base point, thus $[v]=[w]\in S(X)$.

*surjectivity*: Let $[f]\in S(X)$.Suppose $X$ is path-connected. Then $\pi_1(X,x)\cong\pi_1(X,x')$ for all $x,x'\in X$. In particular $\pi_1(X,f(1))\cong\pi_1(X,x_0)$. We clearly find an element $v\in\pi_1(X,f(1))$ where $P(v)=f$ and therefore via the isomorphism an element $v'\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$ such that $P(v')=P(v)=f$.

*conjugacy*: Suppose $P([f])=P([g])$ that is $f$ is homotopic to $g$ via homotopy $H$ not preserving base point. I now need to make sure that $H$ is a homotopy of loops, but I don't see how to do that.

I would appreciate tips on if my current approach is correct and how to approach and finalize the other statements.

Comment: The converse of the surjectivity proposition just needs you to find a loop in the non path-connected space $X$ which is not in the image of $P$ - simply choose a constant loop in a path component which does not contain the base point. I'm a bit short of time so can't help quickly with the conjugacy part but hopefully someone else can.